# MySQL How to select mulipie rows then send to another query

Tags: mysql

I hava a Table ,I can use

```
SELECT `event_id` FROM `event` WHERE 1
```

to get mulipie rows event_id , and I put event_id in this query

```
SET @event_id = XXXX;
SELECT * FROM(
(SELECT `event_id`,`author_id`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`type`,`rate`,`description`,`photo_id`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) AS `timestamp` 
FROM `event`) AS `event`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `thumb_up_count` FROM `thumb_event` WHERE `event_id` = @event_id AND `thumb_state` = 1) AS `thumb_up_count`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `thumb_down_count` FROM `thumb_event` WHERE `event_id` = @event_id AND `thumb_state` = 2) AS `thumb_down_count`,
(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT `thumb_state` FROM `thumb_event` WHERE `event_id` = @event_id AND `user_id` = ?) , 0) AS `thumbed`) AS `thumbed`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `comment_count` FROM `event_comment` WHERE `event_id` = @event_id) AS `comment_count`
) WHERE `event_id` = @event_id;
```

I can use `SET @event_id = 0000;` to set `event_id` , but how I can put all `event_id` from select in that query

Comment: @Downvoter, can you explain your downvoting?

Comment: Likewise the upvoter

Answer (score 1):

If i understoods, maybe what you need it's an IN clause:

```
WHERE `event_id` IN (SELECT `event_id` FROM `event` WHERE 1);
```